# Задачка на паскаль

Tags: pascal

Поправьте код а то что то у меня он некорректно работает

```
program corekey;
label first,second,third;
var a,x,b:real;
p:char;
begin
write('ax+b=0 ');
first:
write('write a ');
read(a);
p:='y';
p:='n';
second:
if a=0 then
write('Banned 0! Input a again?(y/n) ');
read(p);
if p='y' then goto first;
if (p<>'y')and(p<>'n') then goto second;
write('write b ');
read(b);
x:=-b/a;
write(x);
third:
write('Begining again? (y/n) ');
read(p);
if p='y' then goto first;
if p='n' then
write('Press Enter!');
if(p<>'y') and (p<>'n') then goto third;
read;
end.
```

Comment: Очень хорошо было бы, если бы Вы написали что этот код должен делать - так намного легче разобраться и найти ошибку!..

Comment: а в чем именно заключается проблема? Чем проявляется некорректная работа? 

напишите лучше поставленную задачую

Comment: несколько раз выводит  Banned 0! Input a again?(y/n) да и это не учебное задание просто тренируюсь то что мне задали бвло гораздо проще и уменя работало а это глючит

Comment: Некорректность в выводе "Press Enter!write a"? Если да, то write("Press Enter!") должно стоять после if...goto thrird. Кроме write есть еще процедура writeln (первый вывод "ax+b=0 write a")

Comment: Да там от Goto надо избавиться (не понимаю зачем оно нужно)! Я раньше тоже этот оператор часто использовал, но меня препод отучил, и, видимо, не напрасно!..

Comment: нет не это
 я ж сказал где проблема что то там не то

Comment: тот кусок кода alexlz не трогайте

Comment: нужно было всего лишь поставить вопрос немного по другому: не "вот вам код, сделайте до толка", а примерно "Я нашел ошибку, но исправить не могу, подскажите, кому не трудно"

использование меток считается плохим стилем программирования, старайся их избегать, или вообще забудь, что они существуют, здесь лучше использовать циклы

напиши условие, подумаем, поможем

Comment: мне с этим помогите(учту)

Comment: сечас паскаль скачаю и посмотрю, что там не так

Comment: строчки   

p:='y';
p:='n';

можно викинуть, они итак нечево не меняют, поскольку дале следует

read(p);

которий задает значение р

Comment: а утебя он много раз выдает Banned 0! Input a again?(y/n) у меня аж 3 раза

Comment: много, тож 3, товю ошибку я понял, щас напишу

Comment: ок давай в скайпе по чатимся а то тут флуд не хочется устраивать

Answer (score 2):

Твоей основной ошибкой, является использование меток, но ее я упускаю.

Когда тяжело разобраться почему программа плужить, на помощь приходят дебагеры (пошаговое выполнение программы)

так вот дживимся пошагово:

после считывания а = 0 выполняется код

if a = 0 then
write ('Banned 0! Input a again? (y / n)');

read (p);

при выполнении условия у тебя выполняется только WRITE, считывание г будет выполняться в любом случае, эти две строки нужно взять в операторные скобки BEGIN .... END

if a = 0 then
begin
           write ('Banned 0! Input a again? (y / n)');
           read (p);
end;
едем дальше, когда доходит до условия

if p = 'y' then goto first;

первый раз она не выполняется, поэтому код идет в условия

if (p <> 'y') and (p <> 'n') then goto second;

а тут уже P имеет непонятно какую значение поэтому она выполняется, и если код снова выполняется от First к проверкам или от Second к проверкам, они выполняются снова и снова, потому значение P не меняется - вот и получается своеобразное зацикливание.

Выход: При выполнении кода после метки менять значение P на какое нейтральное

Реальный выход: использовать цикл с после условием.

Вот код без етого повторения:

```
program corekey;
label first,second,third; 
var a,x,b:real;
p:char;
begin
write('ax+b=0 ');
first:

p:='n';

writeln('write a ');
readln(a);

second :
if a=0 then
begin
write('Banned 0! Input a again?(y/n) ');
read(p);
end;
if p='y' then goto first;
if (p<>'y')and(p<>'n') then goto second;
write('write b ');
read(b);
x:=-b/a;
write(x);
third:
writeln ('Begining again? (y/n) ');
readln(p);
if p='y' then goto first;
if p='n' then  
write('Press Enter!');
if(p<>'y') and (p<>'n') then goto third;
read;
end.
```

Comment: извините у меня кроме этой проблемы была другая а тебе отдельное спасибо

Comment: так проблема решена?

Comment: не срвсем если ввести вместо y/n что то другое он выводит опять также 3 повтора
Banned 0! Input a again?(y/n)

Comment: вы добираетесь из точки A в точку B, через все остальные буквы алфавита,

Comment: через операторы перехода совершенно непонятно что, как и куда? и при этом еще и нужно выполнить кучу проверок, которые глючат. Оператор перхода используется в современном программирования только там, где без него обойтись невозможно, то есть в ассемблере, но в паскале его всегда можно заменить на цикл Repeat ... Until (условие) и при этом избежать целой кучи проверок, если вы решили профессионально заниматься программированием , то советую вам подружиться с циклами, поскольку на работе за операторы перехода можно получить "нагоняй"